# How to have a static URL for serverless framework AWS deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

When I use serverless framework to deploy with `sls deploy` to an AWS endpoint with lambdas and dynamodb, the host of the endpoint changes every time with a different prefix. This is a problem because if I release a client, I won't be able to deploy with serverless again.

For example, a host might look like this: `9svhw8numd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
That `9svhw8numd` part changes each time there is a new deployment.

I've checked the serverless documentation and I can't seem to find anything that tells me how to configure it to have a static URL. How do I keep the host static for each serverless deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is a URL for an AWS API Gateway instance. If you delete and re-create your serverless stack, a new endpoint will be generated. If you don't remove the stack, it'll stay the same throughout multiple `serverless deploy` commands.

If you'd like a custom domain instead of one generated by API Gateway, you'll need to configure a domain name via AWS Route 53. If you're using the Serverless Framework, here's a [good guide](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/) to do that.